# A problem on matrices : Powers of a matrix

Tags: matrices

> If $ A=
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         i & 0 \\
>         0 & i \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> , n \in \mathbb N$, then $A^{4n}$ equals?

I guessed the answer as $ A^{4n}=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        i^{4n} & 0 \\
        0 & i^{4n} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ which actually was the answer.

Can you provide me with the correct method of getting the answer?

 Thank you.

Comment: What you did is correct, just make the observation that $i$ raised to an even power is -. I am not sure if they wanted you to prove this, use induction.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your method, as long as you realize it works only for diagonal matrices; if $A=\pmatrix{x&0\cr0&y\cr}$, then $A^m=\pmatrix{x^m&0\cr0&y^m\cr}$.

Comment: so i cant get it with steps?

Comment: you can do it with induction easily

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can see $A^2=\begin {pmatrix}i^2&0\\0&i^2 \end{pmatrix}$

you assume that it satisfy fo n-1 so :

$A^{n-1}=\begin {pmatrix}i^{n-1}&0\\0&i^{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$

then :

$A^n=A*A^{n-1}=\begin {pmatrix}i^n&0\\0&i^n \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: So should i take n=4n?

Comment: this satisfy for any n and so for 4n too

Comment: okay i understood

Answer (score 3):

Well you're in luck because what you did actually work with diagonal matrices. Let's look at an example :

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
        a & 0 \\
        0 & b \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ be a diagonal matrix then $ A^{2}=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & 0 \\
        0 & b \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
        a & 0 \\
        0 & b \\
        \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        a^2& 0 \\
        0 & b^2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ and more generally :

$$A^n = \begin{bmatrix}
        a^n & 0 \\
        0 & b^n \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

So you guess wasn't wrong at all, it's just that when you have a diagonal matrix, raising it to a power $n$ equals to raising each of it's coefficients to the power $n$.

But keep in mind that this only works for diagonal matrices. If you have a matrix $B$ that is not diagonal, the best way to find $B^n$ is to diagonalize it (if possible), raise it's coefficients to the power $n$ and go back to your first basis.

Comment: your answer is equally correct thank you   +1

Answer (score 2):

Since $A=iI$ and scalars commute with matrices you get

$$A^{4n}=(i)^{4n}I^{4n}=I \,.$$

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it enough to show $A^4=I$ ?